# Flash Builder 4.6 can't see my connected device after updating to android sdk platform-tools r10 (Mac)

Tags: android, flash-builder

I am running MacOSX 10.7.3

While developing android app on my ASUS tablet, updating to android sdk platform-tool r10 resulted in this curious situation -

With platform-tool r9, everything worked fine - adb devices and Flash Builder both are able to detect my tablet and I deployed and debugged successfully.
After updating to r10, I'm still able to see my device when I run adb devices, however, Flash Builder 4.6 can no longer detect my connected device, thus I'm unable to deploy/debug on device.

Instead it displays:

```
[2012-03-03 17:08:59 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2012-03-03 17:08:59 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2012-03-03 17:09:00 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2012-03-03 17:09:01 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
```

Has anyone ran into this same problem with platform-tool r10??
I was wondering if going back to r9 would solve this issue and have been looking for an archived version but couldn't seem to find it - does anyone know where I can get my hands on this older version??